# How ANR Error dialog box is shown on main thread

Tags: android, android-activity, android-anr-dialog

I was just facing ANR(Activity Not Responding) problem. I resolved thought but that ANR suddenly triggers a question in my mind.....

**When ANR Occurs ?**

```
    Reason: When your activity allocates lot of memory in background or UI is 
blocked more than 5 seconds.
```

**Who displays Alert Dialog ?**

```
    Our activity is a main thread and Main thread can update/manipulate any UI 
elements. Showing Dialog is kind of change in UI.
```

My question is

Who is showing the ANR Alert Dialog?

Can anyone explain me ?

Now my question is if main thread is blocked as ANR error tells us, than how come OS can display ANR Alert dialog box on top of our Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your unresponsive app that's displaying the ANR dialog. It's a [system error dialog](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManager.java#385) displayed by [`ActivityManagerService`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#1124).